# How to pull information based on an ID?

Tags: symfony

I have a entity `Article20000Information`, with a few fields like: `id`, `description`, `manufacturer_id`, `supplier_id`

I have another entity, `Organisation`. It has a list of companies (both manufacturers & suppliers) each with an `id`.

I also have a page which renders a list of Article20000Information data. Currently, it simply displays the data in the table so:

```
| id | Description | Manufacturer | Supplier | Price  |
|----|-------------|--------------|----------|--------|
| 1  |   thing1    |      2       |    5     |  34    |
| 2  |   thing2    |      5       |    2     |  23    |
| 3  |   thing3    |      3       |    4     |  25    |
```

What I need is for the manufacturer and supplier column to display the `name` value from the `organisation` table, based on the id shown.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: Do you use `Doctrine` as ORM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

I needed multiple aliases, which I'd guessed, but I also needed to give them `AS` so that they come out with different column names. This in turn lets twig render the tags.

```
<?php

namespace Regenerys\QMSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class Article20000InformationRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findStuff()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT 
    A.id,
    A.articleNumber,
    A.description,
    B.name as manufacturer,
    C.name as supplier
FROM 
    RegenerysQMSBundle:Article20000Information A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RegenerysQMSBundle:Organisation B WITH B.id = A.manufacturer 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RegenerysQMSBundle:Organisation C WITH C.id = A.supplier '

            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Alexandru for his DQL help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables based on `id` condition.

```
select A.id, A.Description, B.ManufacturName, B.supplierName
from Article20000Information A
left outer join Organisation B
ON B.id = A.id
```

[More info on table joins.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using doctrine, a proper way is to create a `Repository` class, and there write your joined code proposed by @K139 but in `DQL`:

```
class Article20000InformationRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT A.id, A.Description, B.ManufacturName, B.supplierName FROM AppBundle:Article20000Information A
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN AppBundle:Organisation B ON B.id = A.id '
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you will use it:

```
$articles = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Article20000Information')->findAll();
```

Comment: Great stuff, thank you.

This is what I have

`SELECT A.id, A.articleNumber, A.description, B.name, A.manufacturerCatalogueNumber, B.name, A.supplierCatalogueNumber, B.name, A.secondarySupplierCatalogueNumber, A.countedAs, A.amountInsideCounted, A.purchasedAs, A.price, A.whereToFindCertificates FROM RegenerysQMSBundle:Article20000Information A
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN RegenerysQMSBundle:Organisation B WITH B.id = A.id`  

How to I get it so that the manufacturer and the supplier are pulled from the same `Organisation` table?

Comment: Nope you should join them also, as with organisation

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being clear. The ids are in the same table. Right now I'm getting the `name` from `organisation` and it's displaying under manufacturer correctly. I need to run the same thing again for suppliers - to display `name` from `organisation` based on its id.

Comment: I have it! Your repo advice was a huge help, thank you so much.